# Is $e^{-(L+L^T)}$ a positive definite matrix?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

$L$ is a nonsymmetric Laplacian matrix and the zero eigenvalue is simple, is it true that $e^{-(L+L^T)}$ a positive definite matrix (I can be sure that it is non-negative matrix)?

Comment: Please do not use editing of Answers to respond.  You are always able to Comment on Answers to your own Questions, and indeed you have enough reputation to comment anywhere as necessary.  You can include in an edit of your own Question an observation if you like, that every symmetric matrix $S$ satisfies $e^S$ is symmetric positive definite, which is of course the substance of what Fred's Accepted Answer says, so the additional hypotheses on $L$ (nonsymmetric Laplacian, simple zero eigenvalue) are not required for the conclusion, but explaining your context would be more valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=L+L^T$, then $S$ is symmetric, hence all eigenvalues of $S$ are real.

It should be clear, that $e^{-S}$ is symmetric. Now let $ \lambda$ an eigenvalue of $e^{-S}$. Then there is an eigenvalue $ \mu$ of $S$ such that $\lambda = e^{-\mu}$.

Since $ \mu$ is real, we have that $ \lambda >0$.

Conclusion: $e^{-S}$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, then $\exp(A)$ is positive definite.
For $A=UDU^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal and $U$ is orthogonal, and then $\exp(A)=U\exp(D)U^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof for real matrices $L$, whether or not the $0$ eigevalue is simple:

Note that, for *any* real matrix $L$, $L + L^T$ is symmetric, hence is diagonalized by some orthogonal matrix $O$:

$O^T(L + L^T)O = \Lambda, \tag 1$

where

$\Lambda = [\lambda_i \delta_{ij}]; \tag 2$

here the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $L + L^T$; since $L + L^T$ is symmetric, $\lambda_i \in \Bbb R$ for all values of the index $i$; then

$O^T e^{-(L + L^T)} O = e^{-\Lambda}; \tag 3$

notice that

$e^{-\Lambda} = [e^{-\lambda_i} \delta_{ij}]; \tag 4$

furthermore,

$e^{-\lambda_i} > 0, \; \forall \lambda_i; \tag 5$

we thus see that $e^{-\Lambda}$ is a positive definite diagonal matrix.  From (3),

$e^{-(L + L^T)} = O e^{-\Lambda}O^T; \tag 6$

it thus follows that, for any vector $y$,

$\langle y, e^{-(L + L^T)}y \rangle = \langle y, Oe^{-\Lambda}O^Ty \rangle = \langle O^Ty, e^{-\Lambda}O^Ty \rangle > 0, \tag 7$

which says that $e^{-(L + L^T)}$ is positive definite.